# Returning set from Optional

Tags: java, jpa, java-stream, option-type

so I want to return Set from a entity in database. So I have crudRepository and first I return optional Knight from repo looking by id and then I want to get his set of quests from Optionlal

```
public Set<Quest> getAllUserStories(Long id)
    {
        Optional<Knight> knight = knightRepository.findById(id);
       Set<Quest>set = knight.stream().map(k->k.getQuests()).collect(Collectors.toSet());


        return listToReturn;
    }
```

it almost works but its set of sets and I dont know how can I collet something without making it set?
Other question is what if that set of quests is empty, would collect work on  null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your statement “but its set of sets” suggests that the method `getQuests()` returns a `Set<Quest>` already.

To flatten nested structures with a `Stream`, you’d use `flatMap`:

```java
public Set<Quest> getAllUserStories(Long id) {
    Optional<Knight> knight = knightRepository.findById(id);
    Set<Quest> set = knight.stream()
        .flatMap(k -> k.getQuests().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return set;
}
```

But since there is at most one `Knight` and hence one `Set<Quest>` here, there is no need to go the `Stream` route at all. You can simply use

```java
public Set<Quest> getAllUserStories(Long id) {
    Optional<Knight> knight = knightRepository.findById(id);
    Set<Quest> set = knight.map(Knight::getQuests).orElse(Set.of());
    return set;
}
```

following the general pattern for arbitrary properties, in other words, the fact that this property has a `Set` type doesn’t matter. All you need, is a suitable default value for the empty optional. Here, `Set.of()` provides an immutable empty set. It’s similar to `Collections.emptySet()`, except that it has stricter `null` handling, i.e. does even reject query attempts like `contains(null)`.

If you’re suspecting that there might be code having problems with such a strict `null` handling, you may use `Collections.emptySet()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public Set<Quest> getAllUserStories(Long id){
            //Assuming Knight is a List or Set
            Optional<Knight> knightOptional = knightRepository.findById(id);
            //check here if value is present in the optional or not
            Knight knight = knightOptional.isPresent() ? knightOptional.get() : null;
            if(knight != null){
                return knight.stream().map(k->k.getQuests()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
            }
            return new HashSet<Quest>();
        }
```

Comment: Good idea, but I cant make stream out of knight. in the if statement